# CSRF verification failed. Request aborted. Django 1.10 and Angular 1.6

Tags: python, angularjs, django

I'm working on a single page application using django, djangoRestFramework and Angular1.x. I've implemented a login view using the built in login method, but anytime I make a request to the api, it returns with csrf verification failed.

I wrapped my login view with the csrf_protect decorator like:

```
class LoginView(views.APIView):

    @method_decorator(csrf_protect)
    def post(self, request):
        user = authenticate(
            username=request.data.get('username'),
            password=request.data.get('password')
        )

        if user is None or not user.is_active:
            return Response({
                'status': 'Unauthorized',
                'message': 'Username or password incorrect'
            }, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

        login(request,user)
        return Response(UserSerializer(user).data)
```

And I ran angular.config like:

```
angular.run(['$http', function($http) {
    $http.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
    $http.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
}])
```

When I take out the csrf_protect decorator, it still gives me an error saying
'Request object has no attribute session'.

Also when i'm working on localhost and I visit the django admin page before I try logging in, it doesn't give me an error. I can't figure out the issue here, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Actually this works for me with angular 1.4,

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []).config(function($httpProvider) 
{
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken'
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken'
});
```